# creating a sequence number for each set of combination (PO header & line)

Tags: sqlite

[`PO HEADER Line sequence
4101066609  10     1
4101066609  10     2
4101066609  10     3
4101066609  20     1
4101066609  20     2
4101066609  30     1
4101066609  40     1
4101066609  40     2
4101066609  40     3
4101066609  40     4
4101066609  40     5`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COEi3.png)

For the combination of POHEADER and LINE . I need to generate a sequence number . Here number should be reset to 1 for every new set of combination . 
This is to be done in SQLite .
Column of the data are PO_header and Line . and result should be generated like it is mentioned above .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequence number is the number of rows that have the same `poheader` and `line` values. To differentiate the rows with same values, you have to use some unique value (here, the `rowid`):

```
SELECT PO_HEADER,
       Line,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM MyTable AS T2
        WHERE T2.PO_HEADER = MyTable.PO_HEADER
          AND T2.Line      = MyTable.Line
          AND T2.rowid    <= MyTable.rowid
       ) AS sequence
FROM MyTable;
```